# Q-Learning: is the reward cumulative or the delta between the previous and last state?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

Say you are training a Q-Learning function for an agent to play a game (like Defender) in which you use the game's score as the reward:

[image: Q-Learning]

(source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning)

Should the reward parameter be the cumulative score on the new state (i.e. literally the score of the game) or the delta between the old state score and the new state score?

Answer (score 0):

If it would be the cumulative score then any future action that follows a previous scoring would be rewarded which could also reinforce poor actions.
With the change in score you would not have this problem.